# Java scanner doesn't work with .next().CharAt(0) after .nextLine()

Tags: java

I want to know what's happening here.

With this code works perfectly

```
import java.util.*;

public class PruebaPersona {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);


    String nombre, dni;
    int edad;
    char sexo;
    double peso, altura;



    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu nombre?");
    nombre = entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu DNI?");
    dni= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("¿Cuántos años tienes?");
    edad = entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu sexo?(Introduce H/M)");
    sexo=entrada.next().charAt(0);
```

But if I change the order of the inputs, like this
package EjerciciosPropuestos;

```
import java.util.*;

public class PruebaPersona {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);


    String nombre, dni;
    int edad;
    char sexo;
    double peso, altura;



    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu nombre?");
    nombre = entrada.nextLine();


    System.out.println("¿Cuántos años tienes?");
    edad = entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu DNI?");
    dni= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu sexo?(Introduce H/M)");
    sexo=entrada.next().charAt(0);
```

The program jump automatically. The output is
¿Cuál es tu DNI? and whitout wait an input ¿Cuál es tu sexo?(Introduce H/M)

Comment: I think your problem has to do with when you move it around you are putting `nextInt()` before `nextLine()`, thus the linked duplicate, but you didn't make it completely clear which order the entire program is when you change the order.

Comment: Scanner is skipping nextLine() when down there is next() but doesn't happen  when there is nextInt() up of next()

Comment: It has to do if `next` either `nextInt` is _before_ a `nextLine` due to not consuming the line terminator, not after.  After seeing your edit, I can confirm what I said originally is what is happening.  Your `nextInt` is used before `nextLine` causing the issue, you are getting confused on where the problem is.  Please read the link I gave, it answers your question.

Comment: I've already edit it with the code order

Comment: Yes I already read your edit, the link I gave is what is happening in your code.  I told you what the issue is two times...All you would need to do to fix it is put an _extra_ `entrada.nextLine()` after `entrada.nextInt()`.

Comment: Thank you very much Nexevis!